# Put asp.net literal inside a control that will not load css or js

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

There is a literal on a page that loads in css and js.  I can't modify the code behind, but I want to modify the front end code so that the literal dumps the css and js into a control that will not load the css and js.

Is this possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wish to disable that js and css? If so try Mode="Encode" on the literal. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: oh, sounds promising

Comment: I encoded it and put it inside an anchor/div with display none,  problem solved.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set Visible="False" ? Unless it has been forced to 'True' from the code-behind...

Comment: visible="false" is what I tried first, perhaps it is case sensitive, but it really doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Put the literal inside a control you can set Visible=False or display: none;, then set Mode="Encode" on the literal.  This will do it.